# Accessing Sophos WebAdmin on Virtual Machine?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, sophos

I installed Sophos Free Home UTM on Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager and cannot access the webadmin GUI from outside the Virtual machine.  I have changed the network adapter from Nat to bridged adapter but it still does not see the Sophos Home UTM.  I have tried to ping the correct IP address of 192.168.2.100 and it does not respond and also do not see that IP address listed in ifconfig.
I do not know what to try next; any help would be great.

```
C:\Users\kwjor_000>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : TheFalcon
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B8-2A-72-B8-24-43
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-02
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e839:a212:8e40:de73%2(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369754151
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-4C-85-0E-B8-2A-72-B8-24-43
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-A8-CD-0C-6D-28
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A2-A8-CD-0C-6D-27
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::84ee:2799:e6a1:fe37%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.186.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 4:04:46 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 7:34:47 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.186.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 553668694
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-4C-85-0E-B8-2A-72-B8-24-43
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9d3c:e0a:8740:cb13%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.202.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 4:04:47 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 7:34:47 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.202.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 570445910
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-4C-85-0E-B8-2A-72-B8-24-43
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.202.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Wireless-N 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-A8-CD-0C-6D-27
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::35f6:6e7c:6fd1:23f4%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.41(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 12:46:31 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, September 23, 2017 8:04:52 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 77637837
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-4C-85-0E-B8-2A-72-B8-24-43
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\kwjor_000>
```

Comment: You really need to provide all the pertinent information of your network. How's about starting with an ipconfig /all output of the machine you are trying to connect from. And the network configuration of the UTM. UTMs don't have a single IP address. They use two network interfaces and sit in between your computers and the internet. This makes me wonder what you are trying to accomplish on a home based virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I don't see any interfaces on your machine with an IP address in the range 192.168.2.x so how did you come up with that IP for the UTM? If it's not on he same "network" as your other machines it's not reachable. Are you sure you're in bridges mode?

Comment: I am in bridges mode, the IP address is provided by UTM as being the address to access the WebAdmin GUI which runes the UTM.  Does it matter what OS it specified?  Like I picked Linux 2.6/3.x/4.x32Bit, is this an older version of linux that does not support Wifi?

Comment: It's a virtual machine, so it doesn't "see" wifi. It sees a "virtual network adapter" that is bridged to some other physical interface on the host. The UTM has to be configured to be on your network. I'm not sure why it randomly picked 192.168.2.100 but like I said there are usually 2 interfaces on a UTM, it is functionally inert with only 1. If you're just trying to review the web UI then change that 192.168.2.100 address to some unused IP address on your actual network.  Taking a closer look at your ipconfig you cut off the most important info which was the wifi connection. Copy and paste.

Comment: Copy and paste a complete ipconfig /all output in to a code block and I can probably provide you an answer. Remove the image you posted there isn't actually any useful information in it. The useful information was cutoff.

Comment: Can you please spend 5 minutes and format your question?  It’s unreadable in its current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect. Now we see that your computer is connected to wifi with an IP address of 192.168.0.41.

Specifically your interface is configured like this:

```
IP: 192.168.0.41
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
DNS: 192.168.0.1
```

So, for simple testing purposes reconfigure the UTM to be on the same network, using an IP address that is currently unused.

As an example, change the 192.168.2.100 address to a configuration that matches your network. We'll guess that 192.168.0.250 is not used:

```
IP: 192.168.0.250
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
DNS: 192.168.0.1
```

Don't worry if you don't have an option for gateway or DNS. Like I said, a UTM usually has at least 2 interfaces and if the 192.168.2.100 interface is the "LAN" or "Internal" interface it won't have a gateway or DNS setting because that usually IS the UTM.

Make the change above and access your UTM with the new IP.

Comment: Hmmm, that seem to help I could ping that address but was unable to load the WebAdmin GUI, the website timed out.  Any more help would be great.

Comment: Did you try https://192.168.0.250:4444 ?

Comment: This is the issue with only one interface. I don't know if it is the WAN or LAN interface.  Have you seen this guide? https://www.sophos.com/en-us/medialibrary/PDFs/documentation/sophosutmsoftwarewebadminqsgen.pdf?la=en

Comment: Yes I have seen the guide, when I entered the 192.168.0.255:4444 I got a different error screen.

Comment: What different error though? It is specifically https that should be used.

Comment: This is a copy of the error when 192.168.0.250:4444  is entered.

Comment: Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Got it to work after changing from http to https thank you so much for all your help.